# How do I set formatting for a dynamically added column in Infragistics WebDataGrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, infragistics, webdatagrid

I'm currently working with a utility that was written using the Infragistics WebDataGrid control. The tool allows a user to select a table from a drop-down list at which point it runs a stored procedure to get data from SQL Server which it then binds to the grid.

Everything gets a default format, which for datetime columns is simply `MM/DD/YYYY` in this case. There is a request to include the time component for at least one of these columns.

After much searching I've tried to add code to the `_InitializeRow` event handler for the grid, but I can't seem to get it quite right. Here's what I've come up with:

```
if (e.Row.Index == 0)
{
    foreach (GridRecordItem field in e.Row.Items)
    {
        if (field.Column.Key == "InsertedOnCC")
            field.Column.FormatValue = "{0:g}";
    }
}
```

This gives me an error that `FormatValue` cannot have a value assigned because it is a method group.

This was pieced together from several sources, none of which did quite what I wanted to do. For example, one piece of sample code just always assumed that the column in question was the first column, so I had to add the `foreach` loop.

I've seen a lot of mention of `BoundDataField` and `DataFormatString`, but I can't seem to actually find how to access those.

NOTE: I'm actually a SQL Developer, not a C# developer, so please be gentle. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to sort this out by casting the `Column` as a `BoundDataField` then using the `DataFormatString` from there:

```
        if (e.Row.Index == 0)
        {
            foreach (GridRecordItem gri in e.Row.Items)
            {
                BoundDataField field = gri.Column as BoundDataField;

                if (field.Key == "InsertedOnCC")
                    field.DataFormatString = "{0:g}";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the info above, I was able to get this to work. It's cleaner. It does not require the loop:

```
TryCast(.Rows(0).Items.FindItemByKey("MyColumnName").Column, Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls.BoundDataField).DataFormatString = "{0:G}"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).